# Hiding the keyboard on iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

My app has two text fields in it's detail split. The first text field will permit the user to enter data by keyboard but the second by a picker presented inside a popover. Anyway, I want to let the keyboard (that will appear after editing the first text field) get dismissed when I press the text field that uses a popover. I used `resignFirstResponder` and the keyboard stays in place but it's disabled, like when I tap any keyboard key nothing happens (even the key to dismiss the keyboard doesn't work). So how can I hide the keyboard?

Comment: Aren't you blocking the main thread somehow? When this happens, pause the application in the debugger and look what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You should **use**

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

not `releaseFirstResponder` (there is no such method)

Comment: releaseFirstResponder is most likely crashing your app thats why you can't tap on anything.

Comment: sorry, it was a typo! i did actually use resignFirstResponder.

Answer (score 0):

As George said, you should call resignFirstResponder

But actually you might want to look at using the inputView property of the textField instead of using the pickerview in a popover.

You can say:
textfield.inputView = pickerview;

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the second `UITextField`? If you're not going to allow user input something with keyboard use UIButton (probably with custom design), show picker on press and update button's text on changes in picker

Answer (score -1):

the most simplest thing to resign responders

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Comment: +1 I really do not understand why this was downvoted, especially without an explanation! Description from docs: `Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.` This is perfect if you don't care about which textfield is the first responder and just want to hide the keyboard. If the textfield is known, then it is probably best just to resign its status directly, but this is definitely still extremely valid! (although with the OP's updated question this is not as useful).